# Newton's method for multidimensional functions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Can Newton's method be used to find the root of a function f :  $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$.
Can anyone provide a proof for this?

(I have checked the method of solving system of equations with newton's method, but in all the cases that I could find, the number of equations were equal to the number of variables. In this case however, this is not true and thus the Jacobian would not be invertible.)

Edit: This [paper](http://benisrael.net/Newton-MP.pdf) does what I am looking for, but I can't seem to understand the assumptions made in the proof. Whether they are trivial and always valid, or whether they are valid only in some special cases.

Comment: "the root": either such a system is impossible or it is indeterminate. In any case, Newton is not sufficient as it computes a single solution at a time.

Comment: The system may be indeterminate, but based on our initial guess, can't we find the closest solution using newton's method?
PS: Here's a paper which is what I am looking for, but I don't understand the assumptions made in the proof. 
http://benisrael.net/Newton-MP.pdf

Comment: It is not guaranteed even in one-dimension that Newton's method will "find the closest solution".  For isolated roots of smooth functions, if we start "close enough" (initial approximate root within a *basin of attraction*) to a root, Newton's method will converge to that root.

Comment: Right now, I am happy with finding any solution of the system.

Comment: I wish for more details of your motivating application.  For example, if $n$ and $m$ are not to be equal, surely it ought to be known whether $n \gt m$ or $m \gt n$.

Comment: I am using this method to solve some geometric constraints which are not a fixed number. Hence one cannot say whether m>n or n>m. My experience tells me that the system usually converges to a steady state, when the system is solvable and in case it is not, it goes to a trivial solution (like all the points may converge to a single point).

Comment: You can always use Newton's method with a pseudo-inverse instead of the inverse of the Jacobi matrix. This will give you a close solution, for some definition of the word "close", in the underdetermined case and a point with minimal residual for the overdetermined case. Use QR decompositions to avoid computation of the full pseudo-inverse. -- This is exactly what the paper is about.

Comment: @LutzL , I am trying to do the same. Can you explain what is said on the starting few lines of page 3? If T is the pseudo-inverse of J, how can we assume the equations (10) (11) (12) and (13) ? Are they always valid?